# Project only nested objects in mongodb for dynamic field names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection named logins. The structure is as follows,

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "N1",
  tasks: {
    project1: {
      task7: {
        count: 10
        time: 1.2
      },
      task3: {
        count: 56
        time: 1050
      }
    },
    project25: {
      task7: {
        count: 25
        time: 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the details displayed for "task7" irrespective of the "project" level. Something like below, is it possible?

```
db.logins.find({tasks.*.task7.count})
```

Comment: I think your schema structure is not right.

Comment: You can directly use like: `{
  "tasks.project25.task7.count": 1
}`. But, yes, your schema is not correct. It will be very difficult to query further.

Comment: Your key needs to similar in each document but currently every key is different in tasks object.

Comment: I'm just a user of this database. I have no control over the schema design. But depending on our business the key needs to be dynamic as I can understand. Anyway thanks for the replies. Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

As your field names are dynamic & you can't list down all the dynamic keys :

```
{ "tasks.project1.task7.count": 1, "tasks.project2.task7.count": 1,  "tasks.project25.task7.count": 1 }
```

Instead try below query which uses MongoDB's native [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Convert `tasks` object into an array ([{k:...,v:...},{k:...,v:...}]) - here we're projecting only `tasks` field */
    {
      $project: { _id: 0, tasks: { $objectToArray: "$tasks" } }
    },
    /** Iterate over tasks array & re-shaping objects inside tasks & forming a new array of [{k:...,v:...},{k:...,v:...}]
     * We're using `arrayToObject` to convert array to object back again
     */
    {
      $project: {
        tasks: {
          $arrayToObject: { 
             $map: { input: "$tasks", in: { "k": "$$this.k", "v": { task7: { count: "$$this.v.task7.count" } } } } 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7-SQ_gFSy3H)

**Note :** I would highly recommend to avoid dynamic field names which causes several issues while reading or updating existing documents. You design your data very well & the way it should be - You'll write it in a preferred way once & read it n num of times with ease, otherwise if you don't believe on better schema design while writing then you've to do this tedious process on every read, which is not preferred & can be costly.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution. Is there a way to flatten the array so that I can only see results without nested objects. Like in a plain text file.

Comment: @NilupaRupasinghe : Do you mean like this : https://mongoplayground.net/p/76rAqsh9f-P ? If yes, all you need is not to create object `task7.count` at `v` instead replace that with `v` part with :: `"v": "$$this.v.task7.count"`..

Comment: yes something like this. But I see if "task7" is not in the document then it would give an error. Does this mean that in all documents is it essential to have the that key. Because in practical situation there are documents without "task7".https://mongoplayground.net/p/L-O9gGBlai5

Comment: @NilupaRupasinghe : So do you wanted to project only `projects` that have `task7` right ? Try this : https://mongoplayground.net/p/FxjR150tZhx

Comment: Whoa...yes, this is what I wanted to do. Thank you very much, this is great. As one last request, can I also filter it for project level. Ex: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gP-Sr2RSWuv if I wanted only for "project25" and "task7" results to display over all documents, can it be done?

Comment: @NilupaRupasinghe : Check this :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/MC3hP_OsyrA

Comment: yes this worked. Thank you very much not only for the answer, but I have a lot to learn from it.

Comment: @NilupaRupasinghe : Please do accept it, that way your question is complete with a working answer..