# Project only nested objects in mongodb for dynamic field names - extension of original question

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am querying a database with a structure almost exactly like the data described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952309/project-only-nested-objects-in-mongodb-for-dynamic-field-names/61958290#61958290), with dynamic field names.

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "N1",
  tasks: {
    project1: {
      task7: {
        count: 10
        time: 1.2
      },
      task3: {
        count: 56
        time: 1050
      }
    },
    project25: {
      task7: {
        count: 25
        time: 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[This code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FxjR150tZhx) provided in an answer does almost exactly what I need to do, except that I would like to project all fields within task7 (i.e., count and time), not just count. Code copy-pasted here:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      tasks: {
        $objectToArray: "$tasks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "tasks.v.task7": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tasks: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              $map: {
                input: "$tasks",
                in: {
                  "k": "$$this.k",
                  "v": "$$this.v.task7.count"
                }
              }
            },
            cond: "$$this.v"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Could anyone help me tweak the code so that I can retrieve more than one field? I have been trying to, but I am a novice, and so far no luck.

UPDATE: It would be great if I could get the output so that documents are nested under each id, and look something like below:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "N1",
    "tasks_project1": {
        "k": "task7",
        "v": {
          "count": 10,
          "time": 1.2
}
},
    "tasks_project25": {
        "k": "task7",
        "v": {
          "count": 25,
          "time": 10
        }
      }
  }
```

UPDATE #2: Ruben provided the answer in a comment below that provides the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this, using `objectToArray` and `unwind` to go through each level until I can finally find the information I want with a `match`.

Then you could format your output as you want with a `project`.

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bnktu_yGPMl)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "id": 1,
      "name": 1,
      tasks: {
        $objectToArray: "$tasks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$tasks"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "id": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "tasks.k": 1,
      "tasks.v": {
        $objectToArray: "$tasks.v"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$tasks.v"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "tasks.v.k": "task7"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Awesome this is all the info I need, just not exactly in the right form. I see this gives me multiple documents returned per id. Is it possible to have all info returned within each id?

Comment: Yes, you can group the documents again with `$group` and finally, format this information as you want using `$project`.

Comment: If you update you question with the desired output, I could help too.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Updated with desired output.

Comment: You could use this https://mongoplayground.net/p/1SRl5sPwACI

Comment: I would update the answer explaining the query when I have a little more time